# If statement logic - read left to right?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have an if statement in vb.net that reads something like this:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(someDate) Or CDate(someDate) > DateTime.Now Then
    'Do stuff here
End If
```

When someDate = Nothing, the app barfs. I could have sworn that these statements read left to right and as soon as it found a matching condition it would enter into the If code block.

I can write another statement that just does a null check. This results in no errors. Could someone clarify this?

Comment: `OrElse` will short circuit the second evaluation.  `DateTime.TryParse` would eliminate both tests

Comment: Thank you. I hate vb.net

Comment: whats that about the workman who blames the tools?  how does that go...?

Comment: C# **also** has both normal and short-circuit conditions. `&` - `&&` equals `And` - `AndAlso`; `|`- `||` equals `Or`- `OrElse`... Vb.Net has nothing to do with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *do* go from left to right, the problem is you're using `Or`, which evaluates every condition.  You need to use the short circuit version, [`OrElse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx):

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(someDate) OrElse CDate(someDate) > DateTime.Now Then
    'Do stuff here
End If
```